# LTV Calculator MySQL

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have two tables let's call these 'transactions' and 'users'.  The transactions table has an email address and the 'users' tables have an email addresses as well - this is the connecting primary key.

What I'd like to do is craft a query that will 'add' transactions from the 'transactions' table wherever an email address matches by adding the transaction_value amount to a field called 'LTV'

I.e. in pseudo-code Update users set LTV = LTV + (transactions value from transactions table) where (email on 'transactions' ) = (email on users).

what would be the syntax in MYSQL that perhaps uses an inner join?

Here is a Select Query that works to identify the users.

```
SELECT
Transactions.`Customer_Email`,
users.Email,
Transactions.Price,
users.`Name`
FROM
Transactions
INNER JOIN users ON Transactions.Customer_Email = users.Email
```

How would you adapt this query to 'add' i.e. increase the LTV column (lifetime value - not average) - the sum total of the customers' sales with us so as a row is processed if there is an additional transaction in the 'Price' column it increases the value?

Comment: can you provide the SQL scripts to create your tables and populate them with data as well as what your desired result set would look like?

Comment: That's not relevant - the fields (examples) above are sufficient to answer the question. 

Something like Update LTV=LTV+Transactions.Price --- the remainder of the query would need to be an inner join type. The only field names that are relevant are the PRICE from the transactions table and the LTV from the users table.

Comment: it is relevant if it helps others to accurately and efficiently answer your question. there isn't enough information in your original post for someone to give you an accurate answer to your question. you have to understand, all we have is what you put in your post. the easier you make it for others to help you the more likely you will be to get an answer to your question. if you would provide the additional information that I suggested it would be a lot easier to help you out

Comment: I'll ask my developer. I just wanted to post this here to the community for educational purposes and I respectfully disagree there is plenty of field names here to properly answer the question. The users table has more than 100 fields in it and its not relevant for educational purposes, nor is it relevant to populate with data. This is a general SYNTAX question.  I'll answer my own question as soon as my development team gives me the answer.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE users u SET LTV = ( SELECT SUM(t.Price) FROM transactions t WHERE t.Customer_Email=u.Email )
```